# How to display the database value based on categories using Django

Tags: python, django

I have Column fields are Task Type,Date,Schedule .I need to display the values in templates like Task type and their date, schedule.I have number of date and Schedule for one Task Type.
Like this way i need to filter and check condition :
I Know the Design to display like this format.But,I need to display data's by Categories wise.

```
**Meeting:**
    1.Date:2017/28/4 -Schedule:With Client
    2.Date:2017/29/4 -Schedule:With Team
**Demo:**
    1.Date:2017/28/4 -Schedule:demo to Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for task in db %}
   {{ task.TaskType }}
   {{ task.Date }}
   {{ task.Schedule }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I need this format                                                                                                                               Meeting:                                                                                                           
    1.2017/28/4,With Client                                                                              
    2.2017/28/4,With Client

Comment: In views.py: db = db.objects.all().filter('-date')